# how to find the subject?

Tags: grammar

> AAA now appears to have come under pressure from BBB, joining other major corporate figures in China.

How can we make sure that **joining** is related to AAA, instead of BBB?
Could you please give me an example for the opposite situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the word order.

**Joining other major corporate figures in China, AAA now appears to have come under pressure from BBB.**

Word order is a powerful tool in English, but its extensive vocabulary is another tool. So we can also think about word choice. Whether **join** is the best word to use is dubious because there is frequently an overtone that **joining** is at least partially voluntary. To avoid any such implication, there are numerous ways to recast the sentence. For example

**Like other major corporate figures in China, AAA appears to have come under pressure from BBB.**

Answer (score 0):

The linking of the word joining to AAA is implied. If it were the opposite you could say:

> BBB is pressuring AAA, joining other major corporate figures China.

In this case, it would be implied that BBB is joining other major corporate figures. Your sentence make sense.